# Base Class Pointer to derived class inherited function call

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance

I am trying to read data from a .txt file, then create a new oject as the base class pointer to store in a vector. I read the data in, and it it all correct, but when I pass it to the constructor for the derived class (it goes to base class default constructor as well) it throws badptr and a random number. I don't know where I am going wrong here and have spent several hours at this point trying to debug it. I'd appreciate any help in trying to figure it out.

Even in the constructor for OneTime.cpp, I set word = "test" and it still didn't put that in the object. I have also tried to take out OneTime constructor, using the Appointment constructor and sending the variables there to no avail.

I probably did something stupid...so yeah, any help would be great.

Here is my code:

Test.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include "Monthly.h"
#include "Appointment.h"
#include "OneTime.h"
#include "Daily.h"

using namespace std;
void main(){
    vector<Appointment*> appt;

    string type;
    string desc;
    string apm;
    int prio, dayz, mon, year, hour, min;

    ifstream myfile("C:\\Users\\Computer\\Desktop\\Problem 2a\\ApptData.txt");

    while(!myfile.eof()){
        string temp;
        getline(myfile, type, ':');
        getline(myfile, desc, ':');
        getline(myfile, temp, ':');
        prio = atoi(temp.c_str());
        getline(myfile, temp, ':');
        dayz = atoi(temp.c_str());
        getline(myfile, temp, ':');
        mon = atoi(temp.c_str());
        getline(myfile, temp, ':');
        year = atoi(temp.c_str());
        getline(myfile, temp, ':');
        hour = atoi(temp.c_str());
        getline(myfile, temp, ':');
        min = atoi(temp.c_str());
        getline(myfile, apm, '\n');

        if(type.compare("OneTime") == 0){
            Appointment* tempOneTime = new OneTime(desc, prio, year, mon, dayz, hour, min, apm);
            appt.push_back(tempOneTime);
            cout << "OneTime object created." << endl;
        }
        if(type.compare("Daily") == 0){
            Appointment* tempDaily = new Daily(desc, prio, year, mon, dayz, hour, min, apm);
            appt.push_back(tempDaily);
            cout << "Daily object created." << endl;
        }
        if(type.compare("Monthly") == 0){
            Appointment* tempMonthly = new Monthly(desc, prio, year, mon, dayz, hour, min, apm);
            appt.push_back(tempMonthly);
            cout << "Monthly object created." << endl;
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Appointment.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef APPOINTMENT_H
#define APPOINTMENT_H

class Appointment{
public:
    Appointment();
    Appointment(string desc, int priority, int year, int mon, int day, int hour, int min, string apm);
    ~Appointment();

    virtual bool occursOn(int year, int mon, int day) = 0;
    virtual void display() const;

protected:
    string desc;
    int priority;
    int year;
    int mon;
    int day;
    int hour;
    string apm;
    int min;
};
#endif
```

Appointment.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Appointment.h"

using namespace std;

Appointment::Appointment(){
    string desc = "\n";
    int priority = 1;
    int hour = 12;
    int min = 0;
    string ampm = "A.M.\n";
    int year = 1900;
    int mon = 1;
    int day = 1;
}

Appointment::Appointment(string word, int prio, int years, int month, int days, int hours, int minute, string apm){
    string desc = word;
    int priority = prio;
    int hour = hours;
    int min = minute;
    string ampm = apm;
    int year = years;
    int mon = month;
    int day = days;
}

Appointment::~Appointment(){
}

void Appointment::display() const{
    cout << this->desc << " at " << this->hour << ":" << this->min << " Priority: " << this->priority << endl;
}
```

OneTime.h

```
#ifndef ONETIME_H
#define ONETIME_H

#include "Appointment.h"
#include <string>

class OneTime : public Appointment{
public:
    OneTime();
    OneTime(string desc, int priority, int year, int mon, int day, int hour, int min, string apm);
    ~OneTime();

    virtual bool occursOn(int year, int mon, int day);

protected:
    string desc;
    int priority;
    int year;
    int mon;
    int day;
    int hour;
    string apm;
    int min;
};
#endif
```

OneTime.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "OneTime.h"
using namespace std;
OneTime::OneTime(){
    string desc = "\n";
    int priority = 1;
    int hour = 12;
    int min = 0;
    string ampm = "A.M.\n";
    int year = 1900;
    int mon = 1;
    int day = 1;
}

OneTime::OneTime(string word, int prio, int years, int month, int days, int hours, int minute, string apm){
    word = "test";
    cout <<  "Word is equal to " << word;
    string desc = "test";
    int priority = prio;
    int hour = hours;
    int min = minute;
    string ampm = apm;
    int year = years;
    int mon = month;
    int day = days;
}

OneTime::~OneTime(){
}

bool OneTime::occursOn(int useryear, int usermon, int userday){
    if(this->day == userday && this->mon == usermon && this->year == useryear){
        return true;
    }
    else {cout << this->day;return false;}
}
```

Comment: I did it! Thanks to Igor. The program works how I need it to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't at all do what you think it does. Take this for example:

```
Appointment::Appointment(){
    string desc = "\n";
    int priority = 1;
    // ...
}
```

This does **not** initialize data members of class `Appointment`. This declares a bunch of local variables, initializes them, then promptly discards them. Data members remain uninitialized. Make it

```
Appointment::Appointment()
    : desc("\n"),
      priority(1)
    // ...
{}
```

Then read about constructor initializer lists in your favorite C++ textbook. Fixing the rest of the code in a similar vein is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

Oh, and make `~Appointment()` destructor virtual, or you'll have a different problem later on.

Comment: I now feel ridiculous, I've been thinking similar to this, but not spot on...Thank you.